# Create component with dynamic styleUrls in angular 9

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I want to make one component and use it several times in another component,Since the templates and logic of this component are always the same and the style is different, I decided to create a single component instead of creating multiple components and just dynamically define the style file.

There is a common method called Lazy Load CSS at runtime which I will include a link to but the problem is this method that the css file is added globally and since all css files have classes of the same name the last file in the DOM Added effects all components (that is, capsulation is not used in this method), so this method is ineffective.

https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-lazy-load-css-at-runtime-with-the-angular-cli

**Finally I put a picture below that clearly shows what I want to do exactly.**

[image]

**player.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-player',
  templateUrl: './player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./player-' + number + '.css']
})
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() number: number;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

**player.component.html:**

```
<p class="title">player works!</p>
```

**player-1.css:**

```
.title {
  color: red;
}
```

**player-2.css:**

```
.title {
  color: orange;
}
```

**game.component.html:**

```
<div>
  <app-player [number]="1"></app-player>
  <app-player [number]="2"></app-player>
  <app-player [number]="3"></app-player>
</div>
```

How can this be done? Any solution is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not allowed in angular

Comment: What is the best alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are solely looking to dynamically change colors, font sizes etc.. you should reconsider making use of global theming.

Whereas if there are major layout differences you have several options:

1. Create a base component class

   - contains all the logic
   - Derive your other components from this component with different 
     styling files.

Benifit of the solution above is that you can also use appropriate naming for the
child components which would make the code/directive more readable.
Instead of using numbers 1,2,3 you would have darkListComponent, lightListComponent etc..

2. Make use of ngClass:

   - `<div [ngClass]="'my-component-style-' + number"></div>`
   - You can still seperate your styling sheets by passing them to your styleUrls in your
     component.ts file. (`styleUrls: ['theme1.scss','theme2.scss']`)
   - Or you can declare all classes in one file for max styling reusability.

   `my-component-style-1,my-component-style-2 {
       ...same styling
     },
    my-component-style-2 {
      color: orange;
    }`

Option 2 is closer to yours and you'd only have to update your template and styling sheet
for it to work.